# Iterating through a text file to find a username and password match in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

The structure of the for loop looks wrong. For some reason it isn't correctly jumping to the 'else' part of the statement. I'm going to try this in the console to simplify things a little and see if I have any luck:

```
def verifylogin():
fin=open("moosebook.txt","r")
data=fin.readlines()
for line in data:
    fields=line.split()
    fields=[i.rstrip("','") for i in fields] #strips the named character from END of field
    fields=[i.replace("'",'') for i in fields]#when reading the list, you want to remoe the ',' so it isn't part of the username or password
    fields=[i.replace("(",'') for i in fields] #simiarly, remove the bracket and replace it
    line=line.rstrip()
    print(fields)

    access_permitted = False
    for counter in range(0,len(fields)):
        if textlogin.get()==fields[counter] and textpassword.get()==fields[counter+1]:
            access_permitted=True
            if access_permitted:
                    welcome=Label(myGui,text="Access Granted. Loading Profile ....")
                    welcome.pack()

        else:
                    denied=Label(myGui,text="Access Denied")
                    denied.pack()
```

Comment: Can you show what `fields` looks like?

Comment: Can you describe the results?

Comment: Are you sure textlogin.get() and textpassword.get() are working?

Comment: Yes, textlogin and textpassword are definitely working. I also tried this:

Comment: results: on entering 'fields[0] and fields[1]' as username and password, it comes up with "Access Granted"...and then several Access Denied. When I enter the next set of username and password it does a similar thing, except starts with a few Access Denied, and then an Access Granted. In other words, it is SORT of working, but not quite ...

Comment: how on earth do I edit the original to provide more info...this is not very user friendly!

Comment: Ah, just tried it and unfortunately the same result. On wrong combo: 12 "Access Denied" messages (which, incidentally, is the number of items in the list on the file). On the right combo, one "Access Granted", and 6 "Access Denied".......Help!

Answer (score 1):

The way your loop is structured, you'll get the "denied" message for every line in the file that doesn't match your username/password, and get the "accepted" message for every line that does match. If you only want to show exactly one message, then wait until the loop ends to create one.

```
access_permitted = False
for i,s in enumerate(fields):
    if textlogin.get()==fields[i] and textpassword.get()==fields[i+1]:
        access_permitted = True

if access_permitted:
    welcome=Label(myGui,text="Access Granted. Loading Profile ....")
    welcome.pack()
else:
    denied=Label(myGui,text="Access Denied")
    denied.pack()
    line=fin.readline()
```

---

I can't say for sure, but it also seems likely that you're going to get an `IndexError: list index out of range` error in the loop, because `fields[i+1]` goes one past the end of the list on the final iteration. I'm guessing that `fields` is a list containing username + password tuples, in which case you should try:

```
for username, password in fields:
    if textlogin.get()==username and textpassword.get()==password:
        access_permitted = True
```

If `fields` isn't a username-password tuple list, you will probably need to try something else.

---

If each item in `fields` contains a user name and password and also other items, try:

```
for row in fields:
    if textlogin.get()==row[0] and textpassword.get()==row[1]:
        access_permitted = True
```

Comment: am going to grab some lunch and then see if that works - gosh, thanks for the quick response though!

Comment: While I believe I've identified the primary problem, I don't think my suggested code is going to work out of the box. `fields[i+1]` is probably going to give an "index out of range" error. I can't yet suggest anything better though, because I don't know how `fields` was created or what its contents look like.

Comment: Have just edited to add contents: >>> ['CoderBlogJ', 'ggs123', 'J', 'Bloggs', 'Male', 'Coder)']
['LovelyMarvJ', 'vin123', 'J', 'Marvin', 'Male', 'Lovely)']

Comment: The output: 12 access denied (on entering nothing). On gettng it right (e.g. CoderBlogJ and ggs123 for username and password) it says "Access Granted" followed by a couple of Access Denied...

Comment: Are you saying my third code block doesn't work? If not, I think we really need to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can replicate the problem on our own machines.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your edit in your question that said you tried what I suggested. That isn't the same as what I suggested. Your indentation is way off.